# Mutually exclusive RadioButtons by row and not by column in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

GridView with 5 columns:
- text
- radiobutton
- radiobutton
- radiobutton
- checkbox

The text column is automatically populated through a binding to a List<>.
About the radiobuttons I need they are mutually exclusive by row and not by column; their value is set by user interaction.

If I set the GroupName property like in the following exemple, all the radiobuttons are mutually exclusives both by row and by column.

Could you please advise? Thanks in advance!

Chris

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="lstWords" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Word" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Word}"/>
        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Frequency" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Frequency}" />
        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Ins"  Width="30">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Name="radioToInsert" GroupName="radioWords" />
                </DataTemplate>     
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Rep" Width="30">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Name="radioToReplace" GroupName="radioWords" />
            </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Del" Width="30">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Name="radioToDelete" GroupName="radioWords" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Inf" Width="30">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="chkToInflect"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the object in the list that the `ListView` is binding to, then you can add a property in that object which uniquely identifies that particular object, just for this purpose. For example:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public void DataObject()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id{ get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can bind your `GroupName` to this property:

```
<RadioButton Name="radioToInsert" GroupName="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Because each row represents a different object in your list, so this `Id` is only shared in the scope of 1 row.

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot! ... and I dind't have to modify my object as the words i have in the list are already a unique, so finally the binding string is GroupName="{Binding Word, Mode=OneWay}".