# Mutually Exclusive CheckBoxes like Grouped RadioButtons

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, radio-button

How do you group CheckBoxes (like RadioButtons can be grouped) so that when one becomes checked, the others are deselected?

**EDIT**

The motivation for using CheckBoxes is that, by default, they allow the user to deselect them, once selected, whereas RadioButtons do not (without additional logic added to them as well).  Additionally, this type of UI element grouping maps more naturally to something like a nullable bool value where there are three valid options: selected, not selected, null (or no selection at all).  This is a valid use case for certain scenarios.  Neither `RadioButton` or `CheckBox` really fulfills this paradigm completely as is.

From a user's perspective the control to accomplish this is really arbitrary as one is simply a circle that is filled in while the other is a square that is filled in and you could easily render either as the other anyway, so I don't think confusing anyone is a big problem here.  I would say a user would be less likely to be bothered by a square where a circle was expected, and more frustrated with being forced into making a decision between two `RadioButton` options that they didn't want to have to chose between.  In reality one could either create CheckBoxes that support grouping or RadioButtons that support deselection to accomplish this and this question is about the former.

Comment: Why don't you use radiobuttons? You'll only confuse the user by using checkboxes behaving like radiobuttons. You could also make textboxes that open up like dropdowns when you click them. But it would be an equally horrible UX choice.

Comment: my answer here did it for me, the easy way, I might add:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135760/mutually-exclusive-radiobuttons-by-row-and-not-by-column-in-gridview/34485366#34485366

Answer (score 0):

I got so frustrated at having to do it in the CodeBehind all the time that I rolled my own class that inherits from `CheckBox` which adds the functionality with the same API that `RadioButton` provides.  It's missing a few things, but here it is for posterity's sake.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace GroupedCheckBoxTest
{
    public class GroupedCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// All the members of the current group
        /// </summary>
        private IEnumerable<GroupedCheckBox> currentGroup;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name that specifies which GroupedCheckBox controls are mutually exclusive.
        /// </summary>
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates when the checked state of the GroupedCheckBox changes
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CheckChanged;

        public GroupedCheckBox()
        {
            // Add only the current checkbox to the group
            // (for now, but potentially always)
            currentGroup = this.SingleItemAsEnumerable();

            // Attach empty delegate so we don't have to keep checking for null
            this.CheckChanged += delegate { };

            // Aggregate all checked changed events
            this.Checked += GroupedCheckBox_Checked;

            // Associate all GroupedCheckBoxs once they are loaded
            this.Loaded += GroupedCheckBox_Loaded;
        }

        // False when any one of the group checked
        void GroupedCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Uncheck everyone else in the group
            foreach (GroupedCheckBox otherCB in currentGroup.Except(this.SingleItemAsEnumerable()))
            {
                // Uncheck the other checkbox
                otherCB.IsChecked = false;
            }

            this.CheckChanged(this, e);
        }

        void GroupedCheckBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If this GroupedCheckBox isn't even part of a group
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GroupName))
            {
                // We don't need to do anything special
                return;
            }

            // The highest parent node we can get to
            DependencyObject parentNode = this;

            // Walk the control tree until we get to the top
            while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentNode) != null)
            {
                // Get the parent of the current node
                parentNode = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentNode);
            }

            // Get all GroupedCheckBox's with the same GroupName as this one
            currentGroup = parentNode.GetControlsOfType<GroupedCheckBox>().Where(cb => this.GroupName == cb.GroupName);
        }
    }

    internal static class GroupedCheckBoxHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetControlsOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in GetControlsOfType<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // usage: someObject.SingleItemAsEnumerable();
        public static IEnumerable<T> SingleItemAsEnumerable<T>(this T item)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Just copy it to GroupedCheckBox.cs and add the appropriate references to your xaml and use it as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:YourProject.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
        <controls:GroupedCheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Stop}" GroupName="1" />
        <controls:GroupedCheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Go}"   GroupName="1" />

        <controls:GroupedCheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Yes}"  GroupName="2" />
        <controls:GroupedCheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=No}"   GroupName="2" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in a [previouse answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8988407/2606322), you can use a RadioButton that is disguised as a CheckBox. Or you do the logic in the code of your ViewModel.

But there is a reason, there is no CheckBox grouping: The semantic of a RadioButton is that only one of many may be selected. A CheckBox signalizes the user, that the boxes are independent of each other.

So I'd recommend to stick to RadioButtons, unless there are any other reasons.